# 404 Not found error while using flask

Tags: python-3.x, flask, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I'm learning web development in python with the flask. The code doesn't show any error, but when I run it, the browser shows Error - 404 Not Found.
Code:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/admin/')
def hello_admin():
   return 'Hello Admin'
@app.route('/guest/<guest>')
def hello_guest(guest):
   return 'Hello %s as Guest' % guest
@app.route('/user/<name>')
def hello_user(name):
   if name =='admin':
      return redirect(url_for('hello_admin'))
   else:
      return redirect(url_for('hello_guest',guest = name))
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Output in Chrome:
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again

Comment: Could you just specify what url returns 404 ? `http://127.0.0.1:5000/admin` for example ?

Comment: Your code actually runs as it is supposed for me. Be careful with upper/lower case letters in the url

Comment: @PRMoureu Yes,localhost:5000 gives the error and I have tried with port:4996 too..That also gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#url-route-registrations):

> An important detail to keep in mind is how Flask deals with trailing slashes. The idea is to keep each URL unique so the following rules apply:
>
> - If a rule ends with a slash and is requested without a slash by the user, the user is automatically redirected to the same page with a trailing slash attached.
> - If a rule does not end with a trailing slash and the user requests the page with a trailing slash, a 404 not found is raised

IMO, you may encounter the second situation.

Comment: I restarted the PC and ran the code with port=4996. This time i put the url according to flask documentation, fortunately this worked. But its not working with port 5000. I dont know why.

Comment: I think there is an application running on port 5000, try to kill it.

Comment: How do I kill it?

Comment: @MaheshHegde ctrl C