# route to Flask encounters 404

Tags: flask

I'm following the steps in https://github.com/twilio/starter-python

Access to http://localhost:5000/ can get expected response though http://localhost:5000/hello just gets 404.

Here part of the code

```
from flask import Flask, Response, request, render_template
from twilio.twiml.voice_response import VoiceResponse
from twilio.rest import Client

@app.route('/hello', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def hello():
    response = VoiceResponse()
    response.say('Hello there! You have successfully configured a web hook.')
    response.say('Good luck on your Twilio quest!', voice='woman')
    return Response(str(response), mimetype='text/xml')
```

I actually run the example on there `python app.py`, the only modification is three system environment variables the app needed.

I can't figure what could cause that. Could someone give a clue?

Comment: Did you create a client instance. The docs says that import is not enough.

Comment: @kate-melnykova Sorry, I kind of misled, I just updated the OP. I actually run the example on there, the only modification is three system environment variables the app needed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. But mine was solved as some other application was running on port 5000. Try changing the port and I think it should work.
Try referring to [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50890629/404-not-found-error-while-using-flask)